# How to force HTML element with set width to be also resizable using CSS3 resize attribute?

Tags: css, resize

I have this simple situation:

```
<textarea style="width:500px;resize:auto"></textarea>
```

Now this works fine and browser displays resize handle in right bottom corner. However I can make box horizontally only larger, but not smaller (example: http://jsfiddle.net/AzJEM/).

I don't want to use javascript as I think there must be some CSS way how to do this. Anyone can give me a hint ?

EDIT: I am interested only in HTML5, so no need to support IE in the answer.

Comment: What browser are you trying this in?  I can make it smaller in Firefox.

Comment: Yeah, just tried it there.  Seems like a [bug in Chrome](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=72948).

Comment: Looks like more of the Webkit issue, because in Safari it is broken too :-(

Answer (score 0):

use min-width option:

```
<textarea style="width:500px;resize:auto; min-width:500px; min-height:120px"></textarea>
```